# How do I read a list of configuration properties into a custom log4net filter

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-filter

I am creating a custom filter in log4net. I've found I can map elements in the config to properties in the filter class like this:

```
<filter type="ConsoleApplication1.CustomFilter">
    <FooKey value="FooValue"/>
</filter>

public class CustomFilter : FilterSkeleton
{
    public string FooKey { get; set; }

    public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        return FilterDecision.Accept;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is set a list of items like this:

```
<filter type="ConsoleApplication1.CustomFilter">
    <FooKey value="FooValue"/>
    <FooKey value="BarValue"/>
</filter>

public class CustomFilter : FilterSkeleton
{
    public string[] FooKeys { get; set; }

    public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        return FilterDecision.Accept;
    }
}
```

If this is possible, how would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the code responsible for this behavior in the `SetParameter` method of the `XmlHierarchyConfigurator`. What transpires is that:

- If the xml element references a property, then there will be an assignation
- If the xml element references a method, the method will be called with the xml parameter

You cannot assign an array from the *.config file since the configurator only handles scalar values. You can however create a method that will push the new parameter to your custom filter:

```
public class CustomFilter : FilterSkeleton
{
    public string[] FooKeys { get; set; }

    public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        return FilterDecision.Accept;
    }

    public void AddFooKey(string text)
    {
        var temporaryFooKey = new List<string>(FooKeys ?? new List<string>().ToArray());
        temporaryFooKey.Add(text);
        FooKeys = temporaryFooKey.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And then in your configuration file you can do:

```
<filter type="ConsoleApplication1.Filters.CustomFilter">
  <FooKey name="AddFooKey" value="FooValue"/>
  <AddFooKey value="BarValue"/>
</filter>
```

Please note that if you don't want to change the name of the xml element you can use the `name` attribute in order to designate what part of the filter must be accessed, and that you can also use directly the method name.